# find rout from a to b

Tags: routes, graph-algorithm

I want find rout from a to b using public transport. Suppose I'm found path from a to b(i.e. sequence stops from a to b), but how create route(i.e. go from A to D on the bus 3, then take a bus 15 from D to B)? I use depth first method, to create graph connecting stops by transport (considering connecting by length).

Comment: What do you mean by "route"? Do you mean "shortest path"?

Comment: @stephan, I edited my question. It's not matter "route" is "shortest path" or "path"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotate each direct connection (i.e. edge in the graph of your transportation map) between two stops with all the bus lines that serve this part of the connection. Traverse the path and select any of the bus lines from the first edge. Every time, your recent bus line selection is not available on the next edge, you need to change busses. You might want to do backtracking in order to find the connection with the least stops.